# Ubuntu 18.04 compile php7.4

Tags: php, oracle, ubuntu-18.04

How to configure PgSQL support when Ubuntu 18.04 source code installs php7.4?
Compilation information:

```
./configure \
--prefix=/home/ubuntu/application/php7.4 \
--with-config-file-path=/home/ubuntu/application/php7.4/etc \
--with-fpm-user=www --with-fpm-group=www --with-fpm-systemd --with-openssl \
--with-kerberos --with-system-ciphers --with-external-pcre --with-pcre-jit \
--with-libxml --with-zlib --with-bz2 --with-curl --with-external-gd --with-webp \
--with-jpeg --with-xpm --with-freetype --with-gettext --with-gmp --with-mhash \
--with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-mysql-sock --with-mysqli --with-pdo-dblib \
--with-pdo-firebird --with-pdo-mysql --with-zlib-dir --with-pspell \
--with-libedit --with-readline --with-pgsql --with-pdo-pgsql --with-pdo-oci \
--with-snmp --with-sodium --with-expat --with-xsl --with-zip --with-fpm-acl \
--with-valgrind --with-pear --with-cdb --with-iconv --enable-fpm \
--enable-fd-setsize=2048 --enable-embed --enable-phpdbg --enable-phpdbg-webhelper \
--enable-phpdbg-debug --enable-phpdbg-readline --enable-rtld-now --enable-sigchild \
--enable-dtrace --enable-libgcc --enable-werror --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar \
--enable-dba --enable-ftp --enable-gd --enable-gd-jis-conv --enable-intl \
--enable-json --enable-mbstring --enable-pcntl --enable-shmop --enable-simplexml \
--enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm \
--enable-mysqlnd --enable-sockets --enable-soap --enable-calendar --enable-dom \
--enable-exif --enable-fileinfo --enable-filter --enable-mbregex --enable-pdo \
--enable-session --enable-dmalloc --enable-mysqlnd-compression-support
```

Error message:

```
configure: error: You need to tell me where to find your Oracle Instant Client SDK, or set 
ORACLE_HOME.
```

Excuse me, how to solve this? Thank You!

Comment: If Oracle Client is installed, set environment variable ORACLE_HOME to the directory where it has been installed.

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence says you want PgSQL but you've tagged it 'oracle'.  You have a lot of extensions enabled; do you need them all? Which database are you trying to support?

Run `./configure --help` to see the syntax to use for PDO_OCI:

```
  ...
  --with-pdo-oci[=DIR]    PDO: Oracle OCI support. DIR defaults to
                          $ORACLE_HOME. Use
                          --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/path/to/instant/client/lib
                          for an Oracle Instant Client installation.
```

You can get Oracle Instant Client from [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html).  Download the SDK and also either the Basic or Basic Light package.